# create a Correct histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

**I have a range of data represented in the vector C
and  have the data classes represented by the vector R**

```
    C = [1.71974522292994
1.91974522292994
2.03821656050955
2.13375796178344
2.16560509554140
2.22929936305733
2.35668789808917
2.38853503184713
2.54777070063694
2.61146496815287
2.70700636942675
2.73885350318471
2.83439490445860
2.96178343949045
3.02547770700637
3.31210191082803]

    R = [1.71974522292994
2.03821104580359
2.35667686867724
2.67514269155088
2.99360851442453
3.31207433729818
3.63054016017183]
```

**I need to do a histogram and a curve to overlap Standard Normal**

```
z = histc(C,R);   bar(R,z);
```

**but the vector z that represents the frequency is not correct.**

```
z = [2 4 4 4 1 1]'
```

**on excell is so, and represents well the histogram**

```
z = [1 1 4 4 4 1 1]'
```

**you could suggest a solution using these two vectors?
Tnks**

Comment: this looks like homework.  You should at least pay people good money to get them to do this for you.

Comment: There are no homework,
I'm trying to learn how to use matlab,
this just because we do not have good courses in my university .
I find it very sad that you have written. 
because I see that you've done a university, certainly far superior to mine as quality and university.
But before you write trivial things, programmed the answer. @La-comadreja  and sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Antonio: I don't believe MATLAB is incorrect in calculating the bin count at the specified bins.  It may be just in how both platforms accommodate where the cutoff is.  Can you post what you did in Excel as well? La-comadreja... I'll have to admit... that was kind of a douche thing to say.  There were a million other ways to express your point.

Comment: @rayryeng I can not post images.
I think the score is missing http://it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24bn5sg&s=8#.U3aPfnZDbKc

Comment: No need @Antonio.  Luis Mendo has solved your problem.  Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Matlab's definition of [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

> n(k) counts the value x(i) if edges(k) <= x(i) < edges(k+1)

whereas Excel probably uses the more standard

> edges(k) < x(i) <= edges(k+1)

So essentially you need to move the equal sign from below to above. You can get that either

1. By the trick of **changing signs to both vectors and flipping the second** (to keep it sorted):

   ```
   >> z = histc(-C,-R(end:-1:1))
   z =
        1
        1
        4
        4
        4
        1
        1
   ```
2. Using **the very powerful [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) function** to directly compute the histogram with the equal sign above:

   ```
   z = diff(sum(bsxfun(@le, C(:), [-inf R(:).'])));
   ```

Comment: @rayryeng :-) I've used `histc` sooo many times, and only now do I realize that its definition is contrary to the standard one in probability theory, where the equal sign is above

Comment: This fact I did not know.  I wasn't aware that `histc` was the opposite of what I was taught (a.k.a probability theory).  Thanks for this info!

Comment: @rayryeng But you hinted at the answer in your comment! (I just saw it)

Comment: Yes I did, but I wasn't aware of what exactly the differences were.  I didn't look at the documentation but you know the inner workings of both functions!

Comment: -.-' tnks @LuisMendo   this is a histogram in Excell  it.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24bn5sg&s=8#.U3aPfnZDbKc

Comment: @LuisMendo could you explain the[-inf R(:).']. I'm trying to implement this function using a two matrices C (30x14) and R (30x14). I can say that the matrix R is (7x14) because 23 rows are NaN. NaN of the matrix C vary in each column. I do not know if I explained well.

Comment: @Antonio `histc` counts values between the edges provided as its second input. The `-inf` is so that the first entry of the output counts values lower than the first edge in `R`

Answer (score 0):

I found it helpful to use this 
 `z = histc(-C,-R);`

the loop that I used for inside includes matrices with vectors of different length. I then filled the matrix with NaN

```
C and classe = [30x14] created by vectors with different lengths + NaN
[nr,nc] = size(C);
Freq = NaN*ones(nr,nc);
R = NaN*ones(nr,nc);
CC = NaN*ones(nr,nc);
```

I do not find a way in order to create the correct number of figures with the correct subplot. 
In each figure there must be 4 subplot.

```
for k = 1:4
for j= 1 : nc;

    R = classe(:,j);
    CC = C(:,j);
    FF = Freq(:,j);

        R = R(~isnan(B)); % toglie i valori NaN
         CC = CC(~isnan(CC));

        R = sort(R,'descend'); 
        CC = sort(C,'descend');
```

the line of Plot

```
FF = histc(-C,-R); % Calculate the J-th absolute frequencies

        figure(k); <===?????
         subplot(2,2,k) <=== ????????
        bar(B,FF);
```

reassemble the matrices

```
    if length(B)<nr
         R(length(R)+1:nr)=NaN; % riempie la parte di colonna vuota
      if length(CC)< nr;
           C(length(CC)+1:nr)=NaN;
        if length(FF)< nr;
            FF(length(FF)+1:nr)=NaN;

        end
      end
    end



     classe(:,j)=R(:); % matrice classe
           C(:,j)=CC(:) % matrice Elementi;
        Freq(:,j)=FF(:); %Matrice Frequenze Assolute

end
```

the next steps concerns the in plotting of 3 figures. Each figure contains 4 subplot
I would also be able to superimpose on each histogram a standard normal curve ...
a tip?

tnks

Comment: @LuisMendo. Hallo u see my solution?